# How to restore WIM Baremetal to VMWare

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server-2012, system-restore, windows-backup

I have a WindowsmBaremetalImage of my Windows2012R2 which I took from windows Server Backup.

I would really like to restore that as a VM.

When I try to do that, I get an error saying the disk is too small.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thank you
Best regards,
Neil

Comment: Increase the disk size?

Answer (score 0):

Create a New VM with new HDD space.

Add the Secondary Hard disk with old VMDK and mount it.

Start the installation using Media. Restore from Old VMDK where you stored Baremetal Backup to new one.